# DjangoでApacheとdaphneは共存できるのでしょうか。

Tags: python, apache, django, websocket

[環境]
Linux CentOS 8.3.2011
Python 3.8.3
Django 3.2.9
channels 3.0.4
daphne 3.0.2
Apache 2.4.37

DjangoでChannelsを使用してリアルタイム通信をしたいのですが、今までずっとWSGI環境のアプリケーションしか作ってこなかったので、WebSocketのコネクションでエラーが起きてしまい解決ができません。

調べたところ、ApacheだけではWebSocketを使用できなくてdaphneのようなASGIに対応したWebサーバーが必要だと解釈しました。(そもそもこの解釈であっているのかも不安です。)

とりあえずdaphneをインストールしたのは良いものの

・Apacheを使っているのでdaphneを設定できるのか
・設定できる場合、今までのアプリケーションは継続使用が可能なのか

の2点が気になっているので質問させていただきます。

Django自体の理解も浅いので、間違って解釈しているところもあると思いますが、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。足りない情報等ございましたらお申し付けください。

Comment: それらのキーワードで検索するとこんな記事があるようなので、何か参考になるかもしれません。[Deploy django-channels with Apache2 and Daphne](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54809234/9014308), [How to deploy django channels with Apache and Daphne?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63320463/9014308)

Comment: kunif様　ありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きます。